# Error while performing action: Commit failed (details follow): Server sent unexpected return value (403 Access Denied) in response to DELETE request

Tags: svn, rapidsvn

Error while performing action: Commit failed (details follow): Server sent unexpected return value (403 Access Denied) in response to DELETE request '/svn/repo_name/!svn/wrk/942b321b-bbcf-417b-980f-618f8bd4cc10/danny.php'

Guys I am getting this error everytime I try to commit

Update happen no issues not able to delete and commit anything what wrong...