# Siwtch the SVN reponames from http://repo_path to svn://repo_path

Tags: linux, svn, migration, repository, svn-repository

I want to change the repo url from http to svn is there any way I can do it..

I get an [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754605/error-while-performing-action-commit-failed-details-follow-server-sent-unexp) everytime I commit in http but not in svnserve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use svn switch --relocate current_repo_url new_repo_url

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html

Comment: I did that but now the repo is change I can commit by the copy wont update gets stuck in svn update...